# How to iterate over nested JSON with Map in JSX

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

Not sure how to access the inner part of the json object. I've tried using Map to iterate through the `location` part and get the `capital`  but I get the error `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

If I console.log just `item.location` I get:

```
 Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys..
 If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

So not sure what I need to do in order to render `item.location.capital`

json data:

```
{
  "ip": "100.200.00.000",
  "type": "ipv4",
  "continent_code": "NA",
  "continent_name": "North America",
  "country_code": "US",
  "country_name": "United States",
  "region_code": "LA",
  "region_name": "bogus",
  "city": "place",
  "zip": "90210",
  "latitude": 316,
  "longitude": 123,
  "location": {
    "geoname_id": 1234,
    "capital": "Washington D.C.",
    "languages": [
      {
        "code": "en",
        "name": "English",
        "native": "English"
      }
    ],
    "country_flag": "http://assets.ipstack.com/flags/us.svg",
    "country_flag_emoji": "",
    "country_flag_emoji_unicode": "U+1F1FA U+1F1F8",
    "calling_code": "1",
    "is_eu": false
  }
}
```

React

```
 useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://api.ipstack.com/check?access_key=" + accessKey)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            setIpData(data) 
        }) 
        
    }, [])

 return (
        <div className="ip-results">
           <h5>IP ADDRESS</h5>
          {ipData.ip}
          
           <h5>LOCATION</h5>
         {ipData.region_name}
           
           <h5>City</h5>
           {ipData.city} 

           <h5>zip</h5>
           {ipData.zip} 

           <h5>zip</h5>
           {ipData.location.capital}        

        </div>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be that you have some items that don't have a location key?

Can you try this and confirm if you get the same error:

```
{item.location ? <> {item.location.map((l, i) => (
                    <p key={i}>{l.capital}</p>       
                    ))} </> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

`location` is an Object, not an Array.

```js
"location": {
    "geoname_id": 1234,
    "capital": "Washington D.C.",
    "languages": [
      {
        "code": "en",
        "name": "English",
        "native": "English"
      }
    ],
    "country_flag": "http://assets.ipstack.com/flags/us.svg",
    "country_flag_emoji": "",
    "country_flag_emoji_unicode": "U+1F1FA U+1F1F8",
    "calling_code": "1",
    "is_eu": false
  }
```

And it looks like `capital` has a string value, so you can just put

```
<p>{item.location.capital}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do: `<p>{item.location.capital}</p>` but some items don't have `location key`, i.e on some items you'll get `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't map through `location` because it's an object not array, you can map through the `location` object this way :

```
`Object.keys(item.location).map((item, i)=> {
      // your code here 
      // e.g : console.log(item["capital"]) 
      // output : "Washington D.C."
}`
```

Comment: this didn't work. I get the error : Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: what is your object name ? replace `item`in `item.location` by the ojbect name and try again

Comment: item.location should be the object name since I want to get the "capital".

Comment: i mean the full object not only the location object, data or i don't know

Comment: In my code I have [ipData].map(item, index) ... as the full object and then I try to do your Object keys within that and that's where I get the error.

Comment: if your object name is ipData, write it like this `Object.keys(ipData.location).map` we are maping through the location object, and to access it's keys, we need the name of it's parent object `ipData` as you mentioned above

Comment: I've updated my code above but it still won't work. I think I'm going to give up on this for now. Thanks

Comment: So it seems to be a different issue. I updated my code and I'm not even iterating anymore. What I noticed is if I save my file  and then add ipdata.location.capital it displays but if I manually refresh the page I then get the error: Cannot read property 'capital' of undefined. So not sure why that happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226494/discussion-between-iskandar47-and-oxxi).